# Error regarding missing feature property when training/classify image in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to run a land cover classification in GEE. I have a csv file which I converted and exported as a shapefile in GEE. The problem is when I specify the column name containing the land use class, I get the error below.

> classification: Layer error:
>   Property 'land_use_5' of feature '00000000000000000011_0' is missing.

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/15a705dc1133e6978f09e5113bbbcb99

```js
var rwanda = ee.FeatureCollection("users/sbrightaboh/edem");
print(rwanda)
//var count = rwanda.aggregate_count("_land_use_category_alias_class")
//print(count)
//var lookupIn = ee.List([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
//var lookupOut = ee.List([6,5,4,3,2,1,0])
//var remaped   = rwanda.remap(lookupIn, lookupOut, "land_use_c,C,254")
//print(remaped)
Map.addLayer(rwanda,{color:"red"},'Rwanda');

//var values = ee.Dictionary 



// Input imagery is a cloud-free Landsat 8 composite.
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1');

var image = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite({
  collection: l8.filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'),
  asFloat: true
});

// Use these bands for prediction.
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B10', 'B11'];

// Load training points. The numeric property 'class' stores known labels.


// This property of the table stores the land cover labels.
var label = 'land_use_1';

// Overlay the points on the imagery to get training.
var training = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: rwanda,
  properties: [label],
  scale: 30
});

// Train a CART classifier with default parameters.
var trained = ee.Classifier.cart().train(training, label, bands);

// Classify the image with the same bands used for training.
var classified = image.select(bands).classify(trained);

// Display the inputs and the results.
Map.centerObject(rwanda, 11);
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.4}, 'image');
Map.addLayer(classified,
             {min: 0, max: 2, palette: ['red', 'green', 'blue']},
             'classification');
```

Answer (score 4):

- None of your assets are shared so we can't replicate the error - please share assets if you are going to include them in the linked script.
- The error message does not seem to have been generated by the linked script you provided, because 'land_use_5' is not used in the script.

**I can replicate the error in the following example** that demonstrates the need to filter out features from the `training` feature collection that have `null` property values, which is likely what is causing the error in your case.

Here, I've mocked up a feature collection that includes a `null` value for 'prop1' (note the third feature) and used it for training and predicting. The result is the same error message regarding a missing property value.

```js
// Mock up a feature collection with a null value for one of the properties.
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection([
 ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-122.0888, 37.1845]), {'prop1': 1}),
 ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-121.9982, 37.1374]), {'prop1': 2}),
 ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-122.0908, 37.1259]), {'prop1': null})
]);

// Get an image to train and apply classification to.
var img = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
  .filterBounds(fc)
  .first();

// Define the property to predict and what bands to use.
var label = 'prop1';
var bands = ['B4', 'B5', 'B6'];

// Overlay the points on the imagery to get training.
var training = img.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: fc,
  properties: [label],
  scale: 30
});

// Train a CART classifier with default parameters.
var trained = ee.Classifier.cart().train(training, label, bands);

// Classify the image with the same bands used for training.
var classified = img.select(bands).classify(trained);
print(classified);
```

> Property 'prop1' of feature '2_0' is missing.

If I filter out `null` values from the training feature collection and then try training and applying the classifier again, the operation is successful.

```js
// Filter out the null property values and try again.
var trainingNoNulls = training.filter(
  ee.Filter.notNull(training.first().propertyNames())
);

// Try taining a classifer and applying it with the filtered training collection.
var trained = ee.Classifier.cart().train(trainingNoNulls, label, bands);
var classified = img.select(bands).classify(trained);
print(classified);
Map.centerObject(fc, 11);
Map.addLayer(classified, {min: 1, max: 2});
```

[image]

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/656ba6e4194c0a631b040f8f1591a5d6?as_external)